# Threading loading images from a device to a tableView in swift

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, uitableview, nsoperationqueue

I can't find anything online about threading loading an image from a device and scrolling smoothly through a tableview. There is one on [ray wen](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift) about this, but it doesn't really help me for my situation.

Does anybody have any advice or code which would help to allow a tableview to scroll smoothly and load images from the device's temporary directory?

Answer (score 1):

i did exactly as mentioned at tutorial, but with modification for nsoperation subclass

this is methods for fetch

```
-(void) updateData
{


    [self.pendingOperations.downloadQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSArray *filePathes = [self recursiveRecordsForResourcesOfType:@[@"png", @"jpeg", @"jpg",@"pdf"] inDirectory:documentsDirectory];
        @synchronized (self) {
            self.documents = filePathes;
            NSLog(@"documents count %@", @([self.documents count]));
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            //Run UI Updates
            [self.delegate modelDidUpdate:self];
        });

    }];


}

- (NSArray *)recursiveRecordsForResourcesOfType:(NSArray *)types inDirectory:(NSString *)directoryPath{

    NSMutableArray *filePaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSMutableDictionary *typesDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (NSString *type in types)
         [typesDic setObject:type forKey:type];

    // Enumerators are recursive
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:directoryPath];

    NSString *filePath;

    while ((filePath = [enumerator nextObject]) != nil){

        // If we have the right type of file, add it to the list
        // Make sure to prepend the directory path
        if([typesDic objectForKey:[filePath pathExtension]]){
            //[filePaths addObject:[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath]];
            CURFileRecord *record = [CURFileRecord new];
            record.filePath =[directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath];
            record.fileName = filePath;
            [filePaths addObject:record];
        }
    }


    return filePaths;
}
```

this is .m for subclass

```
- (void)main {

    // 4
    @autoreleasepool {

        if (self.isCancelled)
            return;
        NSData *fileData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:self.fileRecord.filePath];
       // self.fileRecord.fileData = fileData;
        if (self.isCancelled) {
            fileData = nil;
            return;
        }

        if (fileData) {
            UIImage *newImage;
            if ([[self.fileRecord.filePath pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"pdf"])
            {
                CGPDFDocumentRef doc = [CURDocumentViewerUtilities MyGetPDFDocumentRef:fileData];
                newImage = [CURDocumentViewerUtilities buildThumbnailImage:doc withSize:CGSizeMake(64, 96)];
            }
            else
            {
                newImage = [CURDocumentViewerUtilities makePreviewImageFromData:fileData];
            }
            self.fileRecord.previewImage = newImage;
        }
        else {
            self.fileRecord.failed = YES;
        }

        fileData = nil;

        if (self.isCancelled)
            return;

        // 5
        [(NSObject *)self.delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(imageDownloaderDidFinish:) withObject:self waitUntilDone:NO];

    }
}
```

With update func i've fetched pathes to proccess, and nsoperation subclass loads images. Works fine with 2000 images in fullhd - smoothly and without any lugs